# how to convert currency from EGP to USD with paypal rates

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, currency

trying to convert currency from EGP to USD but always receiving error message "Currently the system does not accept the currency EGP"
in express checkout Api

Answer (score 2):

PayPal did not hold the EGP as a currency that they are accepting currently. You may need to use the listed currency to make a transaction. Since EGP is not listed as a currency that PayPal is accepting, thus it is impossible to do the conversion on PayPal. For more currency support in PayPal you can view it [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/#header).